# Python: Prevent URL from encoding in Django view

Tags: python, django, url-encoding

In Django view URL is generated dynamically like this

```
<a href="{% url 'users' info.user_id info.full_name '?tab=tags' %}" role="button" class="my">votes</a>
```

Django automatically encode this URL . But i don't like this since user can't view this encoded url .

I have tried following semantics to disable this but none of them work .

1. `{% autoesacpe off %} 
     <a href="{% url 'users' info.user_id info.full_name '?tab=tags' %}"role="button" class="my">votes</a>
   {% endautoesacpe %}`
2. `<a href="{% url 'users' info.user_id info.full_name '?tab=tags'|safe %}" role="button" class="my">votes</a>`

   Note : Using Djnago 1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the GET parameters after the `{% url %}` tag:

```
<a href="{% url 'users' info.user_id info.full_name %}?tab=tags">
```

Comment: GET parameters after the `?` question mark are not passed to the url dispatcher.  So when you access the `/users/123/somename/?tab=tags` url the dispatcher tries to match only the `/users/123/somename/` part of the url.

Comment: But when i use this regular expression `r'^users/(?P<user_id>\d+)/(?P<full_name>[-a-zA-Z]+)$'` for url matching then it failed and complains error .

Comment: Error occurs when we use `<a href="{% url 'users' info.user_id info.full_name '?tab=tags' %}"role="button" class="my">votes</a>` in view . Then it gives NoReverseMatch .error .

Comment: Your regex uses two groups (`user_id` and `full_name`) but in the `{% url %}` tag you trying to resolve url with three groups.  Of course this url will not match.

Comment: What are those three groups ? IMO there are only two `user_id` and `full_name` .

Comment: The third group is `?tab=tags`.  So to solve the issue you have to move this GET parameter out of the `{% url %}` tag.

Comment: Thanks for taking out your precious .